# Whats the advantages and disadvantages of using Socket in IPC

Tags: c, sockets

I have been asked this question in some recent interviews,Whats the advantages and disadvantages of using Socket in IPC when there are other ways to perform IPC.Have not found exact answer .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Compared to pipes, IPC sockets differ by being bidirectional, that is, reads and writes can be done on the same descriptor. Pipes, unlike sockets, are unidirectional. You have to keep a pair of descriptors if you want to do both reads and writes.

Pipes, on the other hand, guarantee atomicity when reading or writing under a certain amount of bytes. Writing something less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes at once is guaranteed to be delivered in one chunk and never observed partial. Sockets do require more care from the programmer in that respect.

Shared memory, when used for IPC, requires explicit synchronisation from the programmer. It may be the most efficient and most flexible mechanism, but that comes at an increased complexity cost.

Comment: could it be the case of some unblocking advantage of IPC sockets?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is too simplified an answer, yet it is an important detail.  Sockets are not supported on all OS's.  Recently, I have been aware of a project that used sockets for IPC all over the place only to find that they were forced to change from Linux to a proprietary OS which was POSIX, but did not support sockets the same way as Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Another point in favour of sockets: an app using sockets can be easily distributed - ie. it can be run on one host or spread across several hosts with little effort.  This depends of course on the nature of the app.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets allow you a few benefits...

- You can connect a simple client to them for testing (manually enter data, see the response).
  This is very useful for debugging, simulating and blackbox testing.
- You can run the processes on different machines. This can be useful for scalability and is very helpful in debugging / testing if you work in embedded software.
- It becomes very easy to expose your process as a service

But there are drawbacks as well

- Overhead is greater than IPC optimized for a single machine. Shared memory in particular is better if you need the performance, and you know your processes are all on the same machine.
- Security - if your client apps can connect so can anyone else, if you're not careful about authentication. Data can also be sniffed if you're not encrypting, and modified if you're not at least signing data sent over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Using a true message queue tends to leave you with fixed sized messages. If you have a large number of messages of wildly varying sizes this can become a performance problem. Using a socket can be a way around this, though you're then left trying to wrap this functionality to become identical to a queue, which is tricky to get the detail right on, particularly aspects like blocking/non-blocking and atomicity.

Shared memory is quick but requires management (you end up writing a version of malloc to manage the SHM) plus you have to synchronise and lock it in some way. Though you can use libraries to help with this the availability depends on your environment and language.

Queues are easy but have the downsides listed as pros to my socket discussion.

Pipes have been covered by Blagovests answer to this question.

As is ever the case with this kind of stuff I would suggest reading the W. Richard Stevens books on IPC and sockets. There is no better explanation than his! :-)